# Set label font size for layer via Python

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, labeling, symbology

I have some ArcMap addin that creates new layer and add it into table of content. I need to set up labels for that layer.

I have made some script for labeling layer:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
data_frame = mxd.activeDataFrame

layer_divide = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "layer", data_frame)[0]
if layer_divide.supports("LABELCLASSES"):
    for lblclass in layer_divide.labelClasses:
        lblclass.expression = "[OBJECTID]"
        lblclass.showClassLabels = True

layer_divide.showLabels = True
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

This add labels, but I don't know how to change font size of that labels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Labels in ArcMap can have formatting codes within the expression, so something like:

```
lblclass.expression = '"{}" + [OBJECTID] +  "{}"'.format("<FNT size = '24'>","</FNT>")
```

might work for you.  This is adding font tags around your ObjectID into a label expression `<FNT size = '24'> + OBJECTID + </FNT>`

Comment: Thank you! That expression worked for font size. What about layer symbology? Don't you know hot to set it?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see you had two questions - please ask this as a separate question.

Comment: OK, I ask new question here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179139/create-symbology-for-new-layer-using-python-arcpy-mapping